# What is the range of ports that is usually used in the traceroute command?

Tags: ports, traceroute

I wanted to know if there is a range which is usually used for destination port that is used in traceroute command. Like the starting address for destination port is 33434. but is there some standard range which is preferred for traceroute ?

Answer (score 9):

Using UDP for traceroute is considered by some poor practice, because UDP is supposed to be a data-carrying application protocol.  ICMP `ECHO_REQUEST` is the preferred method, though **there is no standard**.  The main reason to use ICMP is that UDP can carry a payload, so allowing it through a firewall has greater security implications; for the end-user it's more likely to be blocked.  It's also possible for an application to use the UDP ports resulting in potentially unwanted side-effects.  Despite the preference for ICMP, classic [`traceroute(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=traceroute&manpath=2.11+BSD) and its decedents all use UDP, including the implementations shipped with Mac OS X, most Linux distros, the BSDs and Cisco IOS.

For these UDP implementations the port number is incremented by 1 for each probe so **the highest port number for any given run is equal to *33434 + (max-ttl * probes-per-hop - 1)***.  The default setting for *max-ttl* is usually 32 or 64, depending on the implementation.  The default *probes-per-hop* is usually 1 or 3.  Using the more liberal defaults of 64 and 3, the range would be **33434-33625**.  In practice a max-ttl of 32 is usually more than enough in which case the range would be **33434-33529**.

Also note that IANA has allocated *only* port 33434 to traceroute, but it has left 33435-33655 unallocated.

---

For info on ICMP vs. UDP see: [Why do some common traceroute implementations default to using UDP probes?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9292/why-do-some-common-traceroute-implementations-default-to-using-udp-probes)

Answer (score 4):

After googling I found out that 33434 is the port that is used as the base port for `traceroute`.

The range goes to `33434 + (max-ttl * numberofprobes - 1)`, that usually means

- `max-ttl = 30`
- `numberofprobes = 3`

Answer (score 3):

[Traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) works by [sending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets, which are their own protocol entirely. No ports.

In more detail - traceroute sends ICMP echo packets starting with a TTL of 1. That causes the packet to return a failure at the first router. Then a TTL of 2 - which brings it to the second router. TTL is increased until the destination is reached. The set of routers found along the way is the traced route.

Comment: We can specify the destination port where the udp packets are send to the destination .(I am going for linux implementaion) .

Comment: Why do you prefer a UDP packet over the standard ICMP echo?

Comment: actually i have a assignment in my college and I need to add some options to it . the orignal code provided to me uses UDP .

Comment: What does the assignment ask you to do?

Comment: to add the port option to the command . It internally uses 33434(default value) as the destination port but I need to add option to the command thru which we can specify the destiantion port .

Comment: ICMP is the standard way to do a traceroute, UDP is nonstandard. I'd suggest a default range above port 1000 so that you don't need to be root to run your program. If you need to have a live service on the other end, then look at the [list of well known ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) and offer some of them as defaults. If you don't need a service on the other end, then ports above 10000 are somewhat less likely to have services running on them.

Comment: This answer is true for Windows `tracert`, or *nix `traceroute -I`. *nix `traceroute` uses UDP 33434 (and up) by default.